# GroupBy in LINQ return me invalid values using Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I am using `EntityFramework 4.0` in my application. I have a stored proc that takes `int` as parameter. i have imported this proc as function import in my application using Entity Framework. This proc return me two columnn `Name` and `Number`. I am grouping this result using LINQ query

```
var availName = dataContext.sp_GetAvailable(1).ToList().GroupBy(x => x.TXT_NAME).Select(x => new { Name= x.Key, Communication = string.Join(",", x) });
```

It groups the `Name` but Value return as procedure name ie. `Communication = string.Join(",", x)` communication returns me `sp_GetAvailable` as value.

What am i missing ??

Comment: I would suspect something like `string.Join(",", x.Select(xi => xi.Number))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GroupBy returns IEnumerable where 
IGrouping has 
Key of type x.Key 
and 
Value of type IEnumerable, where T is type of x (not a string)

To get what you want you should use:

```
var availName = dataContext.sp_GetAvailable(1).ToList().GroupBy(x => x.TXT_NAME).Select(x => new { Name= x.Key, Communication = string.Join(",", x.Select(c=>c.Number)) })
```